# Product Information on Hover - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hover

Have a fairly default install of WordPress and WooCommerce on a client's site. I am looking to move the default product information on top of the product image and have it show on hover. I have made a fairly basic outline of how it should work below.

[image]A current link to the page in question is: https://captaincutz.com/store/

The basic code base from the backend looks something like this, before CSS

```
<li <?php function_exists('wc_product_class') ? wc_product_class( $class, $product ) : post_class($class); ?>>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
    <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="product--thumbnail item--image">
            <div class="item--image-holder">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?><div class="item--overlay"></div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="product--action">
                <?php
                do_action('oasis_shop_loop_item_action');
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product--info">
            <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?>
            <div class="product">
                <?php 
                do_action('oasis_shop_loop_item_action'); 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php 
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); 
        ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

I've tried some basic code edits, as well as absolute positioning the items, which works; but it does not achieve the desired look

Comment: Read this - https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ . Copy your template in your child theme and apply the changes you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code and add CSS min-height and min-width value accordingly in order to cover your whole image product on hover, regardless of screen size. You could also use the hook 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'wc_add_customdesc' );

function wc_add_customdesc() {
    global $product;
    $title = $product->get_title(); 
    $price = $product->get_price();
    ?>
        <div class="descShow" itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post-> post_excerpt ); ?>
            <?php echo '<p class="thedateclass">' .'The title is '. $title . '</p>'; ?>
        </div>
        <style>
        .descShow{
        max-height: 0px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    color:white;
    background-color: rgba(65,65,65,0.6);
    opacity:0%;
   
        }
        
        li.product:hover .descShow{
           justify-content:left;
           vertical-align:center;
           padding-left:5px;
           max-height: 100%;
           max-width: 100%;
           min-height:100%;
           min-width:100%;
           opacity:90%;
           transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }        
        
        </style>
    <?php
}
```